# Outlook taskpane(officejs) addin not showing on ribbon

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to develop a outlook addin using yoman-generator.
The code runs and opens outlook but the taskpane addin doesnot appear anywhere on the ribbon.
Also checked the disabled and inactive addins but the taskpane is nowhere to be found.

Anyone can help me on this please? And I am using outlook 2016

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to check the manifest file for any ribbon UI customizations. If ribbon buttons are not listed there, you will never find them on the UI.

> Also checked the disabled and inactive addins but the taskpane is nowhere to be found.

It seems you have checked the list of COM add-ins, not web add-ins in Outlook. On the `Home` tab you may find the `Get Add-ins` button which opens the Add-ins dialog where if clicking on the `My Add-ins` tab on the left side of the window you may find your add-in listed. If it is not listed there you need to add it by pointing to the manifest file. Before doing that you need to make sure the web server where the add-in is hosted is running and files are accessible.

Comment: I have the same issue as described above, but I'm using Outlook for MS 365. 
The manifest.xml file looks correct and I don't have a "get Add-ins" button in my Home tab. How can I solve that?

Comment: Do you have an Exchange (Office365) account configured in Outlook? Go to the File menu in Outlook. On the backstage view you can find `Manage COM Add-ins` and `Manage Add-ins` buttons. The last one is exactly what you need if you don't get `Get Add-ins` button on the ribbon.